# Intercept XMLHttpRequest request and force a status 200 response in plain JS

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I searched about this everywhere and got mixed results.
I must intercept an **XMLHttpRequest** and **fake a status *200* response** from the backend, using plain Javascript. This is being done for testing purposes.

I managed to get here:

```
const originalXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
const originalXHRSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) {
  this.interceptRequest = url.includes('foo/bar');
  originalXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
};

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
  if (this.interceptRequest) {
    console.log('## INTERCEPTED REQUEST');
    // somehow fake a 200 response
    return;
  }

  originalXHRSend.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This works to an extent, I can intercept the call but I was not able to fake the status `200` response. Is that even possible? If so, how?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the status getter in a similar manner to the other methods:

```js
const originalXHRStatus = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.__lookupGetter__("status");
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.__defineGetter__("status", function() {
  if (this.interceptRequest) return 200;
  else return originalXHRStatus.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Note the deprecation notice for [`__lookupGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__) and [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__). I used the deprecated methods to keep within the style of your redefinitions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to do this without deprecated methods? Don't mind the style :)

Comment: The non-deprecated alternatives are explained in the deprecation notice.